# Pass message about the call to the callee

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have a cakephp application. I have used webrtc for the video chat between peer groups and used XHR for the peer connection.

- Problem: I want to pass a message to the callee about the call so
  that callee can receive the call.

After searching on the Internet I come up with the some solutions:

1. Refresh the page say ( after 5 seconds) and check whether call
   has initiated, If initiated show popup ( Initiation can be checked
   though Database).
2. Make Ajax request to check whether the call has initiated, If initiated show popup ( Initiation can be checked though Database).
3. I came up with the event listeners in the cakephp. But I am not sure whether it will be feasible to show the pop up message to the callee only, not to all the user.

---

1st and 2nd are not efficient, 3rd is efficient but I am not sure about this. Is there any other ways to do this. If third is possible, explain us

Answer (score 2):

Socket programming is perfect use case for your problem. It's kinda similar to your 3rd approach. 
A very high level flow will be

1. Register caller & callee to the server-socket, by some identifier (say name)
2. Caller sends the "calling" signal with callee's name.
3. Server-socket identifies callee by the name
4. Sends the call signal to callee

P.S. Socket is a 2-way communication

Cakephp has socket features. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html

You can also check this out.
https://github.com/thabung/phpSocketExample

Comment: redA Thank you for your response. Is there any example that explains above. I actually don't know how to convert your step into the code.

Comment: @SachinSingh  Try this:- [https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket)     . Hope it helps

Comment: what actually is host var host = "ws://localhost:12345/websocket/server.php"; I am using xampp for the development.

Comment: I can share my XHR code to you. Could you help me to convert my code so that I can use socket feature.

Comment: your email id @redA, by the way I have added the code in the question. My email is spratapsingh11@gmail.com

Comment: @SachinSingh   https://github.com/thabung/phpSocketExample
This is a working example. I have tested personally. You can modify to pass the message. Currently it's a simple chat app, where message is broadcast to all peers. Let me know for any help